# Dimension of a basis for a module using the quotient map

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I'm going through a proof that the size of a basis for a module is uniquely determined and can't see why the following line from my lecture notes follows:

> "We now claim that if $X$ is a basis for the module $M$ then $q(X)$ is a basis for the $k$-vector space $M/IM$. If we assume this then $|X| = \dim_{k}(M/IM)$..."

where $I$ is a maximal ideal in $R$, $q$ is the quotient map $q: M \rightarrow M/IM$, and $k$ is the quotient field $R/I$. I think we also assume that $R$ is an integral domain.

What I don't understand is how the dimension line follows, since surely we have a smaller basis in the quotient module as we no longer have linear combinations of elements in $I$? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, not so "surely"! Obviously $q(X)$ is a system of generators. Then show that it is linearly independent. (It's not necessarily to assume $R$ an integral domain.)

Comment: I understand the method of the proof but not how the equality of dimensions follows from $q(X)$ being a basis for $M/IM$, since intuitively the quotient module could have a lower dimension.

Comment: AFAIK, the dimension equals the cardinality of a basis. Or $X$ and $q(X)$ have the same cardinality, don't you think?

Comment: What if $X$ contains a generator of $IM$? Then $q(X)$ has smaller cardinality, right?

Comment: Have you ever seen a basis containing the zero element? (You said that you know that $q(X)$ is basis.)

Comment: No, it would contradict linear independence, hence why $q(X)$ would be a basis of smaller cardinality

Comment: So, the only thing to show is the linear independence of $q(X)$. The rest follows immediately.

Comment: My thinking is as follows: if $q(X)$ is a basis then $|q(X)| = dim_k(M/IM)$. If $X$ contains a generator of $IM$ then $q(X)$ has fewer elements than $X$, so we cannot have the above equality (in the OP).

Comment: The point is that *any* basis $X$ can't contain an element of $IM$ (why?).

Comment: I can't see why, since elements of $IM$ are linear combinations of elements in $X$, so why can't we have these particular combinations as part of a basis?

Comment: The elements of $IM$ are linear combinations of elements in $X$ **with coefficients in $I$**!!!

Comment: I'm afraid I still can't see why this is so :(

Comment: Recall how an element $x\in IM$ looks like. Write it as $x=a_1m_1+\cdots+a_tm_t$ with $a_i\in I$. Then write every element $m_i\in M$ as a linear combination of elements from $X$. Now look again at the coefficients of $x$.

Comment: Sorry - I meant that I can see that the elements of $IM$ are linear combinations of elements of $X$ with coefficients in $I$ but not how this means it can't be a basis element.

Comment: Well, if $x\in X$ and $x\in IM$ then $x=a_1x_1+\cdots+a_tx_t$ for some $a_i\in I$ and $x_i\in X$. Then or $x\ne x_i$ for all $i$ and thus $x=0$ or $x=x_j$ and then $a_j=1$. Can we have $1\in I$?

Comment: No, because then $I = R$ and so $I$ isn't proper, contradicting $I$ being maximal. Sorry this took so long and thank you for your help! I don't know how to credit you from here but thank you again for helping me see exactly what is happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concern that some basis element can fall in $IM$ is unfounded.

Let $x\in X$. Since $X$ is a system of generators for $M$ the elements of $IM$ have the form $a_1x_1+\cdots+a_tx_t$ with $a_i\in I$ and $x_i\in X$. (For more details see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1747809/generating-system-for-r-module-m-still-generating-mathfrak-am).) If $x=a_1x_1+\cdots+a_tx_t$ then there is $j$ such that $x=x_j$ and $a_j=1$. But $I$ is a proper ideal, so $1\notin I$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

If $M$ is a free $A$-module with basis $X$ (with $n$  elements), the $M\simeq A^n$, so $$M/IM\simeq A^n/IA^n\simeq (A/I)^n=k^n.$$
Thus $M/IM$, being isomorphic to $k^n$ has dimension $n$.